# ESP8266 /ESP12F use flash button as input without using loop()

Tags: esp8266, button

I couldn't find a proper answer anywhere on internet.

I want to use the FLASH button as input in the setup() function and do not use the loop() with deepsleep mode (this part comes later).

I tried demos wherein the button events are sometimes failed to be captured. How can I make it 100% sure to get detected as soon as I press reset or along with reset? Because there is a mismatch in the time when reset is clicked and the flash button press gets detected.

Comment: you want to read in setup if the button is pressed? `pinMode(D3, INPUT_PULLUP); if (digitalRead(D3) == LOW) ...`

Comment: you can't read buttons while resetting, can you elaborate on the goal a bit more?